# Как сделать такой select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи сайта, не судите строго. с js сложновато. Как сделать такой Select, чтобы внутри были пункты которые можно выбрать и ниже была ещё кнопка.

[image]

Может есть плагин какой то ?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Это не select, select так не сверстать, даже и пробовать не стоит, хотя ради изучения этого вопроса можно. Берется select и скрывается средствами CSS. Далее берется обычный список ul>li, у него пункты будут как у нашего select, стилизуется как нужно. Средствами JS отслеживаем клики по нашему списку(ul) и переносим выбранный пользователем пункт в select, готово. Действуйте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема у вас не с JavaScript, а вообще с пониманием верстки, а именно того, как реализуются подобные выпадающие списки.

Берется `select` и скрывается средствами CSS. Далее создается обычный список `ul>li`, у него пункты будут как у нашего select, стилизуется как нужно. Средствами JS отслеживаем клики по нашему списку(ul) и переносим выбранный пользователем пункт в select. Готово.

```js
$('.sorting-dropdown-select').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this)
    .next('.sorting-dropdown')
    .slideToggle('400');
  $(this).toggleClass('sorting-dropdown-select-active');
});

$('.sorting-dropdown-item-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var selectValue = $(this).html();
  var selectDataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $('.sorting-dropdown-select')
    .html(selectValue)
    .toggleClass('sorting-dropdown-select-active')
    .next('.sorting-dropdown')
    .slideToggle('400');

  $('select[name="sorting-select"]')
    .removeAttr('selected')
    .find('option[value="' + selectDataId + '"]')
    .prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.sorting-title {
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.sorting-select-area {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-width: 254px;
  position: relative;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select:before {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(33%, black), color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, black 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 3px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select.sorting-dropdown-select-active {
  color: #e2001a;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select.sorting-dropdown-select-active:before {
  display: none;
}

.sorting-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 17px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0px 17px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sorting-dropdown .sorting-dropdown-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px 0 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.sorting-dropdown .sorting-dropdown-item-link {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.sorting-dropdown .sorting-dropdown-item-link:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.red-btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

button[type='submit'] {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" class="sorting-form">
    <!-- begin Hiding Select -->
    <select name="sorting-select" class="hide">
      <option value="priceLow">Цена по возростанию</option>
      <option value="priceHigh">Цена по убыванию</option>
      <option value="nameAZ">По названию А-Я</option>
      <option value="nameZA">По названию Я-А</option>
    </select>
    <!-- end Hiding Select -->
    <!-- begin Select Custom -->
    <div class="sorting-select-area">
      <span class="sorting-title d-block">Сортировка:</span>
      <a href="#" class="sorting-dropdown-select">Цена по возрастанию</a>
      <!-- begin Sorting Dropdown -->
      <div class="sorting-dropdown">
        <ul class="sorting-dropdown-items">
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="priceLow" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">Цена по возрастанию</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="priceHigh" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">Цена по убыванию</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="nameAZ" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">По названию А-Я</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="nameZA" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">По названию Я-А</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" class="red-btn">Добавить адрес</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end Sorting Dropdown -->
    </div>
    <!-- end Select Custom -->
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

А вот пример, где наш select не скрыт и понятно, что здесь происходит:

```js
$('.sorting-dropdown-select').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this)
    .next('.sorting-dropdown')
    .slideToggle('400');
  $(this).toggleClass('sorting-dropdown-select-active');
});

$('.sorting-dropdown-item-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var selectValue = $(this).html();
  var selectDataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $('.sorting-dropdown-select')
    .html(selectValue)
    .toggleClass('sorting-dropdown-select-active')
    .next('.sorting-dropdown')
    .slideToggle('400');

  $('select[name="sorting-select"]')
    .removeAttr('selected')
    .find('option[value="' + selectDataId + '"]')
    .prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.sorting-title {
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.sorting-select-area {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-width: 254px;
  position: relative;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select:before {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(33%, black), color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, black 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 3px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select.sorting-dropdown-select-active {
  color: #e2001a;
}

.sorting-dropdown-select.sorting-dropdown-select-active:before {
  display: none;
}

.sorting-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 17px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0px 17px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sorting-dropdown .sorting-dropdown-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px 0 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.sorting-dropdown .sorting-dropdown-item-link {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.sorting-dropdown .sorting-dropdown-item-link:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.red-btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

button[type='submit'] {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" class="sorting-form">
    <!-- begin Hiding Select -->
    <select name="sorting-select" class="hide">
      <option value="priceLow">Цена по возростанию</option>
      <option value="priceHigh">Цена по убыванию</option>
      <option value="nameAZ">По названию А-Я</option>
      <option value="nameZA">По названию Я-А</option>
    </select>
    <!-- end Hiding Select -->
    <!-- begin Select Custom -->
    <div class="sorting-select-area">
      <span class="sorting-title d-block">Сортировка:</span>
      <a href="#" class="sorting-dropdown-select">Цена по возрастанию</a>
      <!-- begin Sorting Dropdown -->
      <div class="sorting-dropdown">
        <ul class="sorting-dropdown-items">
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="priceLow" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">Цена по возрастанию</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="priceHigh" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">Цена по убыванию</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="nameAZ" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">По названию А-Я</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" data-id="nameZA" class="sorting-dropdown-item-link">По названию Я-А</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sorting-dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" class="red-btn">Добавить адрес</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end Sorting Dropdown -->
    </div>
    <!-- end Select Custom -->
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: Спасибо! Я еще дополнил для полноты картины и завершения действия я добавил .change(); в конец функции

$('.sorting-dropdown-item-link').click(function(event) {
.....
.prop('selected', true)
.change();
}